# Amazon EC2 - Node Package Manager fails to install modules

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, node.js

I've installed node and, supposedly, all of its dependencies on an Amazon EC2. I can launch a node app and have it work just fine.

However, when I attempt to use npm to install any module, express for example, I get the following error response:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-67 Collaborate]$ npm install express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: express
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:32:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:137:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:109:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:198:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:356:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1238:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.34-37.137.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/Collaborate
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.8
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-2
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: express
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/Collaborate/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

From this error log, is it possible to know what I've done wrong, or what I'm missing?

Comment: Oh and I used this tutorial to set node up on the EC2: http://blog.ryanparman.com/2013/08/10/uploading-web-files-to-a-new-amazon-ec2-instance/

Comment: You seem to be using old versions of Node and NPM. Any reasons why not update them? Also, try pinging https://www.npmjs.org and checking you can get to https://registry.npmjs.org/package/express from your machine.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy updating them fixed it

Comment: Cool! Would you like to leave it like that, or shall I post my previous comment as an answer and you can mark it closed?

Comment: That's best practice. @TravelingTechGuy

Comment: Done - posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using old versions of Node and NPM. Try updating to current versions.